# Which reason types of bounced emails exist?

Tags: postfix, sendmail

I need to get reason statistics for all bounced emails from mail.log.

Which reason types exist?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.answersthatwork.com/Download_Area/ATW_Library/Networking/Network__3-SMTP_Server_Status_Codes_and_SMTP_Error_Codes.pdf

Answer (score 3):

A "Bounce" message is just a normal email message, with the distinction that it was forwarded to the originating address in response to a failure condition somewhere in the delivery path; furthermore, the intervening mail hosts were unable to rectify this failure condition, hence the message is returned to the sender as undeliverable.

A bounce is neither a status, nor a failure reason.

Your own mail server log will only contain a possible reason if your mail server was responsible for generating the bounce message.

Comment: ...and just to clarify, then *content* of the email is not a standard / parsable format.

Comment: But if you have a feeling of the kind of bounces that you get, and you already know that they can be divided in n categories, you may be able to write a program that can classify bounces that you receive in those n categories. Of course this way you may miss a n+1 category that may appear later and handling MIME and bounces in different languages can be a mess. But if such messages are a small percentage it may work.